# Is any way to show text line at the top of QTableView exist?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, label, qtableview

I need something like on the picture below but I can't find a way to do it using Qt 4.3.3...

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the headers or the "There are no items..." text?

Comment: @cbamber85: about "There are no items..." text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a build-in function  that does this . The best way to go is to subclass QTableView and override the draw function to draw some text when there are no elements to show .Use the slot

`int rowCountChanged(int,int)`

to find out when row count is zero.